# Multiprocessing with Pool() takes more time than expected. Always keep running some 1, 2 or 3 workers

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use Pool() to speed up the request task on 33 url in python. However, when the I use Pool().imap_unordered(), I can see that the workers are executed from 1 to 30. And it keep running the 3 other workers for a very long time. My objective is to recuperate the outputs of the whole process. I also tried .imap() and .map(). And there is no big difference. The problem is still there. The next code is just a part of a big code. the variable url is a list of url generated from an other process. Please, I need your advises.

```py
def Url(url):
  util = 0
  # Connect to the URL
  try :
    response = requests.get(url,verify = False)
    if response.status_code != 200:
      return([])
  except:
    return([])
  # Parse HTML and save to BeautifulSoup object
  text = response.text
  util = int(text.count("<tr>")>=1000)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
  out = list(soup.findAll('a'))
  return([[url,link,util] for link in out])

# the variable url is a list of url of size 33
if __name__ == "__main__":
  Output = []
  count = 0
  q = Pool(mp.cpu_count()*(len(url)>=mp.cpu_count())+len(url)*(len(url)<mp.cpu_count()))
  for res in q.imap_unordered(Url,url):
    Output.append(res)
    count += 1
    print(count)
  print("Completed")
```

I want the Output of the whole process.

Comment: Are you sure your pool size is computed correctly? Have you tried to make a pool of constant size? If so, how did it work? Also, don't some URLs take very long to respond?

Comment: Yes I have tried a constant value, there is no change. Actually I am working in Google Colaboratory where multiprocessing.cpu_count() is giving me 40.

Comment: In the code `mp` refers to the multiprocessing objet. `mp.cpu_count()*(len(url)>=mp.cpu_count())+len(url)*(len(url)<mp.cpu_count())` is the size of `url` if this size is less that the number of core (here 40) and 40 if it is greater than 40.